# How to query advanced issue handling on github (use of milestones and projects)?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I'd like to get the repositories that make the most active use of milestones and/or projects. By "most active" I mean something like most cards moved on a project board or most issues added to a milestone.

I tried [GH Archive](https://www.gharchive.org/) which has yearly datasets on [Google bigquery](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/githubarchive:year.2017). I ran this query

```
SELECT
 JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.action')  
FROM
  [githubarchive:year.2017]
WHERE
 type in ("IssuesEvent") 
 and JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.action') in ("milestoned", "labeled", "assigned")
LIMIT
  20
```

and this query

```
SELECT
  type
FROM
  [githubarchive:year.2017]
WHERE
  type IN ("MilestoneEvent",
    "ProjectEvent",
    "ProjectCardEvent")
LIMIT
  20
```

Both return zero results. Does GH Archive not import all events? Am I making a mistake in the queries? Is there another source where I can get this information?

Comment: MilestoneEvents are not included in the timeline, so those won't show up. Maybe the others are missing that caveat in the docs? https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#milestoneevent

Comment: I checked the documentation. It says some event types are not listed on the timeline, but IssuesEvent, ProjectEvent, and ProjectCardEvent are not among them.